# Not able to download the newly added files from TFS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

We are using TFS 2013 (internal server) and use VS 2012 for develop.

I add the new folders and files with content and i check in, after that other users not able to download the newly added files by me. they are getting "HTTP 302 moved temporarily" error.
if already they have the same file then it sync without problem

My team members tried to download the solution by using
get latest version , get specific version, check out 
and none downloads the newly added files

Please help

update : 
just found that we are able to download the files by using the server's name and if user uses the IP then the same problem persists

Team Foundation Server name : part1-part2-1
Team foundation server IP : 10.xxx.x.xxx

Any ideas why not able to download the files by using IP

Update : When i try to download code files as .zip files from Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online) (within intranet only) our proxy restricts to download as .zip file. So i believe visual studio would have been encountered the same. if this is the case is there any way to instruct the visual studio to download the latest version by files

Answer (score 0):

First, please make sure your Team Foundation Server IP didn't changed. And try to connect TFS server by IP such as `http://10.xxx.x.xxx:8080/tfs` directly.

And also turn off the anti-virus software and Firewall, try to download the files again using IP. More info about the ERROR HTTP 302 you can refer this link: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E302.html